# Make navigation bar to lef side of the page

Tags: html, css, windows, testing, web

I have tried every possible way to move navigation bar to left and keeping rest of the page in the between not below the navigation bar, following is the code I am making changes to. If anyone could help, Thank you.

HTML

```
<nav role ="navigation" class="navbar">
          <ul>
            <a href={{ url_for('index') }}><li>Tools</li></a>
            <a href={{ url_for('certification') }}><li>Certification</li></a>
            <li><a href="#">Application1</a>
              <ul class="dropdown">
                <a href={{ url_for('accessing') }}><li>Access</li></a>
                <a href={{ url_for('loading_maintenance') }}><li>Maintenance</li></a>
                <a href={{ url_for('summary') }}><li>Summary</li></a>
                <a href={{ url_for('loading_report') }}><li>Report</li></a>
              </ul>
            </li>
            <li class="disabled">Application2
              <!-- <ul class="dropdown">
                <li><a href="#">How to access</a></li>
                <li><a href="#">Summary</a></li>
              </ul> -->
              
            </li>
            <a href={{ url_for('application3') }}><li>Application3</li></a>
          </ul>
        </nav>
```

CSS

```
.navbar ul {
  background: #006ac3;
  list-style: none;
  margin: 0;
  padding-left: 0;
  display: flex;
  justify-content: space-evenly;
  width: 100%;
}

.navbar li {
  margin-left: 0;
  color: #fff;
  background: #006ac3;
  display: block;
  float: left;
  padding: 1rem;
  position: relative;
  text-decoration: none;
  transition-duration: 0.5s;
  width: 100%;
  text-align: center;
  font-size: 20px;
}

.navbar a {
  width: 100%;
}

.navbar li a {
  color: #fff;
}

.navbar li:hover,
.navbar li:focus-within {
  background: #ffc72c;
  cursor: pointer;
}

.navbar li:focus-within a {
  outline: none;
}

.navbar ul li ul {
  background: #006ac3;
  visibility: hidden;
  opacity: 0;
  min-width: 5rem;
  position: absolute;
  transition: all 0.5s ease;
  margin-top: 1rem;
  left: 0;
  display: none;
}

.navbar ul li:hover > ul,
.navbar ul li:focus-within > ul,
.navbar ul li ul:hover,
.navbar ul li ul:focus {
  visibility: visible;
  opacity: 1;
  display: block
}

.navbar ul li ul li {
  clear: both;
  width: 100%;
}

.dropdown li {
  text-align: left;
}
```

[This is what it looks right now](https://i.stack.imgur.com/o0Fxc.jpg)
[This is what I am expecting to make it look like](https://i.stack.imgur.com/1ePfc.jpg)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can put on the left by setting a `width` for the navbar and adding `flex-direction:column;` to `.navbar ul`

p.s: I suggest put the navbar in a container so later you can add other tags on the right side of it

```css
.navbar{
  width:200px;
}
.navbar ul {
  background: #006ac3;
  list-style: none;
  margin: 0;
  padding-left: 0;
  display: flex;
  flex-direction:column;
  justify-content: space-evenly;
  width: 100%;
}

.navbar li {
  margin-left: 0;
  color: #fff;
  background: #006ac3;
  display: block;
  float: left;
  padding: 1rem;
  position: relative;
  text-decoration: none;
  transition-duration: 0.5s;
  width: 100%;
  text-align: center;
  font-size: 20px;
}

.navbar a {
  width: 100%;
}

.navbar li a {
  color: #fff;
}

.navbar li:hover,
.navbar li:focus-within {
  background: #ffc72c;
  cursor: pointer;
}

.navbar li:focus-within a {
  outline: none;
}

.navbar ul li ul {
  background: #006ac3;
  visibility: hidden;
  opacity: 0;
  min-width: 5rem;
  position: absolute;
  transition: all 0.5s ease;
  margin-top: 1rem;
  left: 0;
  display: none;
}

.navbar ul li:hover > ul,
.navbar ul li:focus-within > ul,
.navbar ul li ul:hover,
.navbar ul li ul:focus {
  visibility: visible;
  opacity: 1;
  display: block
}

.navbar ul li ul li {
  clear: both;
  width: 100%;
}

.dropdown li {
  text-align: left;
}
```

```html
<nav role ="navigation" class="navbar">
          <ul>
            <a href={{ url_for('index') }}><li>Tools</li></a>
            <a href={{ url_for('certification') }}><li>Certification</li></a>
            <li><a href="#">Application1</a>
              <ul class="dropdown">
                <a href={{ url_for('accessing') }}><li>Access</li></a>
                <a href={{ url_for('loading_maintenance') }}><li>Maintenance</li></a>
                <a href={{ url_for('summary') }}><li>Summary</li></a>
                <a href={{ url_for('loading_report') }}><li>Report</li></a>
              </ul>
            </li>
            <li class="disabled">Application2
              <!-- <ul class="dropdown">
                <li><a href="#">How to access</a></li>
                <li><a href="#">Summary</a></li>
              </ul> -->
              
            </li>
            <a href={{ url_for('application3') }}><li>Application3</li></a>
          </ul>
        </nav>
```

Comment: This did helped me, I created container which helped me with the navigation bar on left and rest text in between the nav bar

Answer (score 0):

```
<div class="container">
    <nav role ="navigation" class="navbar"> Your content goes here </nav>
    <div class="content">Your rest of the page content</div>
</div>

.container{
  display : flex;
  justify-content : space-between;
}
.navbar ul {
  background: #006ac3;
  list-style: none;
  margin: 0;
  padding-left: 0;
  display: flex;
  flex-direction : column;
  justify-content: space-evenly;
  width: 100%;
  }
.content{
  flex-grow : 1; /*allow content to fill remaining space */
}
```

Comment: If I study your code, it looks like you have provided a working solution. However, it would be helpful if you explained what changes you made instead of just posting code, and would also be helpful if you show a working demo in a [Stack Snippet](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/358992/ive-been-told-to-create-a-runnable-example-with-stack-snippets-how-do-i-do)